# Using XMLDataProvider as Static Resource to Bind data to ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind data from an XML file to a combobox. I am not seeing any errors, but the ComboBox box is not populating as expected.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxGenre" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,49.864,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource Genres}" XPath="./genre/name" />
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
```

In my App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Genres" Source="Genres.xml" XPath="Genre" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The XML file Genres.xml

```
 `<genreList>
  <genre>
    <name>Swing</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Blues</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Latin</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Pop</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Funk</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Folk</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Ballad</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Christmas</name>
  </genre>
  <genre>
    <name>Western/Bluegrass</name>
  </genre>
</genreList>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Xpath query is wrong for your `XmlDataProvider` registration in App.xaml. It should be `XPath="genreList"` instead of `XPath="genre"`.

Based on the [MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287(v=vs.110).aspx), the registration should be:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Genres" Source="Genres.xml" XPath="genreList" IsInitialLoadEnabled="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that did it.  Now I understand more about how the xpath works. The examples I found before weren't so clear.  Thanks!